# Can't install nodej.s mysql module

Tags: node.js

Somehow, I can't install mysql module into my Node.js. I type the typical "npm install mysql", but it just won't work. This is what it gets:

```
npm install mysql
mysql@2.7.0 node_modules\mysql
├── require-all@1.0.0
├── bignumber.js@2.0.7
└── readable-stream@1.1.13 (isarray@0.0.1, inherits@2.0.1, string_decoder@0.10.3
1, core-util-is@1.0.1)
```

It doesn't do anything; when I check if the module has been installed, it just isn't. What can I do?

Comment: Try npm install --verbose and see if you can find anything.  At least post that bit of logging.

Comment: How do you check the results of the installation? Have you watched folder `node_modules/mysql` in your project folder?

Comment: Yes, and mysql isn't there, only the npm module

Comment: @user2903610 If you're seeing the `npm` module in the directory, you may be looking at the global root (`npm root --global`). Local installations, that are to be used with `require()`, are installed to the current working directory. https://docs.npmjs.com/files/folders

Comment: @user2903610 It's definitely installed and is there.  You probably have a higher level `node_modules` directory where it landed for some reason.  Does `node_modules` exist at all?